# wrong data when pulling webpage source python

Tags: python, http, web, urllib2

I'm using the following python code:

```
def get_data(self, url):
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()
    return data
```

To parse data from a certain website and it worked for a while.
Now something went wrong.
When I use this function now it gives me a source code but different than the one there is
when you open the view-source:*url*
I am using chrome for the regular website view. Is there a way to get the same source code as I see by using the "view source" option? thanks.

Comment: Yeah what exactly is different the actual code or how it's written?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Chrome, but is it possible "view source" show the source including JavaScript-generated content? Whereas your Python code returns "raw" content.

Please note certain web sites return a different content depending the client (and it's supposed capabilities).

All of this being speculative, for a "fair" comparison,  you might compare your result with those obtained using a `wget` or `curl`.